# doxygen alias xrefitem without "list title" parameter?

Tags: doxygen

I'm preparing the code documentation for C code with doxygen. 
I would like to create an Errors section under the Parameters and Returns sections for each function in the output rtf document.

```
/**
 * Some description
 *
 * @param[in]      i4InputParam
 *
 * @error IOError
 * @error RangeError
 */
```

In the online doxygen manual, I found [\xrefitem](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) command for this purpose.
In my doxygen configuration file I have the below aliases definition for @error tags:

```
ALIASES += error="\xrefitem @error \"Errors\" \"Errors\""
```

This alias creates the Errors section in function documentation as I want. However, it also creates an errors list section after TOC and before the file Index sections. I don't want this top level error list section.

The problem is that the "list title" parameter seems to be mandatory.
When I remove the third parameter it does not create neither of those Errors sections. When I set to empty \"\"" it still creates the top level error list.

Do you have any suggestions to force \xrefitem to ignore the "list title" parameter? or Do you suggest any other alternative to perform this operation?